# WiFi Adapter RTL8812AU driver installation fails with the latest kernel: 5.15.0-27-generic (x86_64)

Tags: wireless

All what I do is:

```
apt update
apt install git dkms
git clone https://github.com/gnab/rtl8812au.git
cp -r rtl8812au /usr/src/rtl8812au-4.2.2
dkms add -m rtl8812au -v 4.2.2
dkms build -m rtl8812au -v 4.2.2
```

but it fails on

```
dkms build -m rtl8812au -v 4.2.2

Kernel preparation unnecessary for this kernel. Skipping...
Building module:
cleaning build area...
'make' all KVER=5.15.0-27-generic........(bad exit status: 2)
ERROR (dkms apport): binary package for rtl8812au: 4.2.2 not found
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 5.15.0-27-generic (x86_64)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/rtl8812au/4.2.2/build/make.log for more information.


DKMS make.log for rtl8812au-4.2.2 for kernel 5.15.0-27-generic (x86_64)
Sun  8 May 21:30:30 BST 2022
make ARCH=x86_64 CROSS_COMPILE= -C /lib/modules/5.15.0-27-generic/build M=/var/lib/dkms/rtl8812au/4.2.2/build  modules
make[1]: Entering directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-5.15.0-27-generic'
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtl8812au/4.2.2/build/core/rtw_cmd.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtl8812au/4.2.2/build/core/rtw_security.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtl8812au/4.2.2/build/core/rtw_debug.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtl8812au/4.2.2/build/core/rtw_io.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtl8812au/4.2.2/build/core/rtw_ioctl_query.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtl8812au/4.2.2/build/core/rtw_ioctl_set.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtl8812au/4.2.2/build/core/rtw_ieee80211.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtl8812au/4.2.2/build/core/rtw_mlme.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtl8812au/4.2.2/build/core/rtw_mlme_ext.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtl8812au/4.2.2/build/core/rtw_wlan_util.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtl8812au/4.2.2/build/core/rtw_vht.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtl8812au/4.2.2/build/core/rtw_pwrctrl.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtl8812au/4.2.2/build/core/rtw_rf.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtl8812au/4.2.2/build/core/rtw_recv.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtl8812au/4.2.2/build/core/rtw_sta_mgt.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtl8812au/4.2.2/build/core/rtw_ap.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtl8812au/4.2.2/build/core/rtw_xmit.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtl8812au/4.2.2/build/core/rtw_p2p.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtl8812au/4.2.2/build/core/rtw_tdls.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtl8812au/4.2.2/build/core/rtw_br_ext.o
/var/lib/dkms/rtl8812au/4.2.2/build/core/rtw_br_ext.c:25:10: fatal error: net/ipx.h: No such file or directory
   25 | #include <net/ipx.h>
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
make[2]: *** [scripts/Makefile.build:285: /var/lib/dkms/rtl8812au/4.2.2/build/core/rtw_br_ext.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [Makefile:1875: /var/lib/dkms/rtl8812au/4.2.2/build] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-5.15.0-27-generic'
make: *** [Makefile:1086: modules] Error 2
```

Any idea how to fix that?

Comment: That driver is very old. Try this: https://github.com/morrownr/8812au-20210629

Comment: Unfortunately, it does not work either. The chip is actually RTL8811AU and worked beautifully with older kernels. Is there any chance to make it work?

Answer (score 0):

Access the repo from MX Linux, there is a driver compatible with kernel 5.15
https://mxrepo.com/mx/repo/pool/main/r/rtl8812au-dkms/

Comment: Hi! The link in your answer should be useful, but can you be so kind to also provide some specific instructions for the OP to make use of it? You can [edit] your answer to add the additional info. Thanks!